# md-datepicker (Angular Material) should display only Month and Year in PopUP

Tags: datepicker, angular-material

How I can display only month and year using [`md-datepicker`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker) directive?

Currently, There is no information is available in Angular Material Documentation.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass mode to the md-datepicker directive
`md-mode="month"`

e.g

```
    <md-datepicker ng-model="dateFields.selectedDate"
                   md-mode="month">
```

[image]